# Pass PHP variable to Jade.PHP

Tags: php, pug

I have a Jade template, and I want to pass a PHP variable $str into this template and show it.
So in the template I put

```
{{$str}}
```

and then it got rendered like:

```
<title><?php echo $str ?></title>
```

I want the $str to be shown directly. But it's not mentioned in the [node.php page](https://github.com/everzet/jade.php).

Search online, there's some method like

```
eval("?>".$rendered."<?php");
```

and I believe this is a dirty solution because if my template has something like "?>" then everything would be wrong.

Is there a proper way of doing this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile the template, store it in a `.php` file. Recompiling a file everytime you need it is a bad idea :).
I'd recommend using a md5file (or just md5 the file's content) to know if a file changed or not, and recompiling it on-the-fly.

and then just include it.